# fetch image url at fixed intervals using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am a complete beginner in javascript so I don't even know where to begin. I have a URL that displays a .jpg snapshot. It is served from a video server. I would like to take the image and display it on a webpage with the image being refreshed every 2 seconds. The image will be displayed in a div container with id="snapshot"

Any help or guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For your html, you do the following:

```
<div id="snapshot"><img/></div>
```

Then in your JavaScript you do the following:

```
var url = "some url somewhere";
var snapshotImg = document.querySelector('#snapshot > img');
var updateInterval = setInterval(updateImage, 2000); //start the update every 2 seconds
updateImage(); //immediately update the image

function updateImage(){
    snapshotImg.src = url + "?"+ new Date().getTime();
}
```

In the 'updateImage' function, I added a ? and a time hash to the url so that each time it sets the source, the srcurl is unique. If you don't make it unique each time, the browser will cache the image from the first request, and it won't ever update the image. So, you have to make the url unique, and you that by adding a hash, that is arbitrary, to the end of the url. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Why not `document.getElementById('snapshot')`?

Comment: That would work as well, @AnalPhabet. Both would work.

Comment: @AnalPhabet because this one actually selects the image, not the div?

Comment: Yes. The querySelector allows you to use a css query, instead of selecting the element by id, and then getting the img inside of that. @AnalPhabet